# UIntArray's asIntArray vs toIntArray, what's the different?

Tags: arrays, kotlin, collections

Both `toIntArray` and `asIntArray` looks very similar

**[asIntArray](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/as-int-array.html)**

@ExperimentalUnsignedTypes fun UIntArray.asIntArray(): IntArray
Returns an array of type IntArray, which is a view of this array where each element is a signed reinterpretation of the corresponding element of this array.

**[toIntArray](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/to-int-array.html)**

@ExperimentalUnsignedTypes fun UIntArray.asIntArray(): IntArray
Returns an array of type IntArray, which is a copy of this array where each element is a signed reinterpretation of the corresponding element of this array.

What is their different?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For **toIntArray**, it is a new copy, and changing the content would not change the original item

```
        val uIntArray = UIntArray(3) { 1U }
        val toIntArray = uIntArray.toIntArray()

        toIntArray[1] = 2
        println(toIntArray.toList())  // [1, 2, 1]
        println(uIntArray.toList())   // [1, 1, 1]
```

For **asIntArray**, it is a view of the original, hence changing the content would change the original item

```
        val uIntArray = UIntArray(3) { 1U }
        val asIntArray = uIntArray.asIntArray()

        asIntArray[1] = 2
        println(asIntArray.toList())  // [1, 2, 1]
        println(uIntArray.toList())   // [1, 2, 1]
```